# Azure Cosmos Db document - want to use replacedocumentasync with a removed property in the document

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

```
// I am using code like below
Document doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(collectionLink)
                            .Where(r => r.Id == "doc id")    
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .SingleOrDefault();

doc.SetPropertyValue("MyProperty1", "updated value");
Document updated = await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(doc);
```

**Want to remove "MyProperty2" from the document. How to do this?**

Comment: Please tell if Microsoft.Azure.Document has any way to remove a property from the document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you'd like to update `MyProperty1` property and remove `MyProperty2` property from your document, the following sample code is for your reference.

```
private async Task updateDoc()
{
    string EndpointUri = "xxxxx";
    string PrimaryKey = "xxxxx";
    DocumentClient client;

    client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);

    Document doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("testdb", "testcoll"))
                .Where(r => r.Id == "doc5")
                .AsEnumerable()
                .SingleOrDefault();

    //dynamically cast doc back to your MyPoco
    MyPoco poco = (dynamic)doc;

    //Update MyProperty1 of the poco object
    poco.MyProperty1 = "updated value";

    //replace document
    Document updateddoc = await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(doc.SelfLink, poco);


    Console.WriteLine(updateddoc);
}

public class MyPoco
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}
```

**My document:**
[image]
**Updated:**
[image]

**Edit:**

> this would remove "MyProperty3" and "MyProperty4" as well.

As you mentioned, setting property with null would be also a approach.

```
Document doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("testdb", "testcoll"))
            .Where(r => r.Id == "doc5")
            .AsEnumerable()
            .SingleOrDefault();

doc.SetPropertyValue("MyProperty2", null);

//replace document
Document updateddoc = await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(doc.SelfLink, doc);
```

Comment: Thanks Fred. But this would remove "MyProperty3" and "MyProperty4" as well which are existent in MyPoco.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying. You got it what I was asking for.

I did not want to use `MyPoco` as using `Microsoft.Azure.Document` is the most flexible. Also, using this approach would also remove any `MyProperty3` if it exists with `MyPoco`.

Using `Document` class only, following worked:

```
eachDoc.SetPropertyValue("MyProperty2", null);
```